# Newbie: After adding cases to a switch in C, it breaks

Tags: c

```
switch(ch)
{
        //input a number
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            if(check_original())
            {
                int y = g.y;
                int x = g.x;

                g.board[g.y][g.x] = ch - '0';
                draw_numbers();

                g.y = y;
                g.x = x;
                show_cursor();
             }

        // delete an input from the board
        case '0':
        case KEY_BACKSPACE:
        case KEY_DC:
            if(check_original())
            {
                    int y = g.y;
                    int x = g.x;

                    g.board[y][x] = 0;
                    draw_numbers();

                    g.y = y;
                    g.x = x;
                    show_cursor();
            }
}
```

Problem:   Case '1' through case '9' worked fine.  Then I added case '0', case KEY_BACKSPACE and case KEY_DC.   Although it compiles, none of the cases now work, including cases '1' - '9'.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think you might want to insert some `break` statements somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your cases are falling through. I assume that you should have a `break;` before `case 0:`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `break;`. In C, `switch` has fall-through semantics. Once a case is met, all subsequent cases are exceuted unless a `break;` stops execution.